# big-O notation with fractions and negative exponents

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to determine the order of the following function of t:

f(t) = (a + b/t)<sup>-n</sup> * (c + d*t)<sup>-m</sup>

where a,b,n,c,d,m are positive constants.

I tried the following: Taking limit t --> infinity in the first factor gives a<sup>-n</sup> which is a constant. Therefore

f(t) = O((c + d*t)<sup>-m</sup>) = O(t<sup>-m</sup>)

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you please reformat this expression so that it's more readable?

Comment: What have you done to try and determine the order, other than state the problem?

Comment: Okay, I edited the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your calculation is correct.  You can double check yourself by taking the limit of the original function `f(x)` over your approximation `g(x)`

[image: Big O definition]

If your limit doesn't shoot off to infinity, the function you calculated for big *O* is valid.

Note that if you get a limit of 0, your approximation grows more rapidly than your original function.  Technically overshooting is valid for big *O*, but in common usage you'll want to calculate a tighter upper bound ([big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations))

In your case, the limit of `f(x)` over `g(x)` is `a^-n c^-m`